# Intuition about a proof that no natural number is equivalent to a proper subset of itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, natural-numbers

I'm having trouble developing my intuition about the need for a particular form of proof that Halmos presents in *Naive Set Theory*.

The theorem is on page 53 in the *Arithmetic* section is about the natural numbers:

> In other words, if $n \in \omega$ then $n$ is not equivalent to a proper subset of $n$.

I'll present my attempt at a proof, and then Halmos's more detailed proof. My question is:

**what error have I made in my proof? What assumptions have I made that are not allowed, and that require the Halmos version?**

### My Attempt

The theorem's truth seems like an obvious consequence of the definition of equivalence and an earlier theorem about the natural numbers:

> Every proper subset of a natural number $n$ is equivalent to some smaller natural number (i.e., to some element of n).

It seems trivial to state that if $n$ were equivalent to a proper subset of $n$, then because of this latter theorem it would also be equivalent to a smaller $m$, which is not possible because there are strictly fewer elements in that smaller $m$ ($n \cap m\neq \emptyset$)

Side note - equivalence is defined on page 53:

> Two sets $E$ and $F$ are called *equivalent*, in symbols $E \sim F$, if there exists a one-to-one-correspondence between them.

#### Halmos's Proof

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that you can deduce that if $n$ were equivalent to a proper subset of $n$ then it must be equivalent to some smaller $m\in n$.

The mistake in your argument is the next step: "which is not possible because there are strictly fewer elements in that smaller $m$". Why does that mean it's not possible? What do you mean by 'strictly fewer' anyway? Presumably you mean that "the cardinality of $m$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $n$ and not the same as the cardinality of $m$".

...But showing that the cardinality of $m$ is not the same as the cardinality of $n$ is exactly what you're trying to prove. We're working with a precise notion of 'more/fewer elements than' here, which is precisely the point of the formalisation that Halmos is working with.

It seems obvious to say that $m$ is a smaller number than $n$, therefore it can't be the same size as $n$...but we have to use something quite special about the natural numbers here, because think about what fails with the argument "the even numbers are a strict subset of all the natural numbers, therefore they can't have the same size as them".